# how to manage quanta D51B-1u fans using ipmitool?

Tags: ipmitool

Going by the PDF here: http://www.staroceans.org/e-book/S2B%20IPMI%20Commands.pdf, which is for the SBR firmware found on the D51B-1u quanta Quantagrid 1u server, it seems you should be able to adust the fans using these commands:

```
    61. Fan Command (1U)
Type Command Format Description
In Band
ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x10x0 0x3f
Set BP fan 0 to 63
duties
(=0x3fheximal;
maximum duty is 63)
ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x10x1 0x3f Set BP fan 1 to 63
duties
ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x10x2 0x3f Set BP fan 2 to 63
duties
ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x10x3 0x3f Set BP fan 3 to 63
duties
ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x10x4 0x3f Set BP fan 4 to 63
duties
ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x10x5 0x3f Set BP fan 5 to 63
duties
```

Although this pdf says its for the D51B 1/2u chassis, when running these commands, you get the following error:

```
 ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x10x4 0x3f
Given data "0x10x4" is invalid.
```

Is there a way to somehow get a list of the valid hex values for ipmitool raw to see if maybe it's as simple as changing 0x10x4 to something else?

I tried running the commands for the 2U from that doc, but doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there should be a space in the command.   Check the 2U command just below this one in the guide.

Try this one -

```
ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x1 0x1 0x3f
```

Comment: omg thank you.    the 0x4 was wrong in the manual i guess.. it now works:
Fan_SYS0_0       | 6200 RPM          | ok
Fan_SYS0_1       | 5200 RPM          | ok
Fan_SYS1_0       | 6300 RPM          | ok
Fan_SYS1_1       | 5200 RPM          | ok
Fan_SYS2_0       | 6400 RPM          | ok
Fan_SYS2_1       | 5300 RPM          | ok
Fan_SYS3_0       | 13100 RPM         | ok
Fan_SYS3_1       | 10900 RPM         | ok
Fan_SYS4_0       | 12800 RPM         | ok
Fan_SYS4_1       | 10800 RPM         | ok
Fan_SYS5_0       | 12800 RPM         | ok
Fan_SYS5_1       | 10800 RPM         | ok

Answer (score 0):

Quanta's corresponding IPMI command guide has a typo (of course!) for the 1U server commands related to fan speed controls. The 2U server example command is correct. The 1U example commands are also confusing because the example uses speed 3f (63%). I don't understand why anyone would choose 63% as a good number for an example. The 2U example uses x64 (100% fan speed), which is a more typical example for IPMI fan controls.

The correct syntax for both 1U or 2U versions of the server (and incidentally for most if not all Quanta servers with the ASPEED AST2400 BMC chip) is:

```
ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x00x 0x0{fan_id} 0x{duty_speed}
```

For example, to set fan 3 to 50% duty speed:

```
ipmitool raw 0x30 0x39 0x01 0x00x 0x03 0x32
```

Reference: http://www.staroceans.org/e-book/S2B%20IPMI%20Commands.pdf